# Clearing the value of a text box after the enter key has been pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a site/game for school with a text box. It looks a little like Quizlet (https://quizlet.com).

When the users presses the enter key, the input should be cleared. The problem is: On the computer, it works just fine but on a phone, it leaves an empty line. So the word checker always counts it wrong unless the player removes it with the backspace. Is there a way to remove the enter on a phone? Because I'm having a lot of trouble with it (especially because it's kind of necessary that it works on a phone).

```
// The code I used a year ago to 
resetInput();

function resetInput() { 
  document.getElementById("input").value = ""; // 
  document.getElementById("opmerking").innerHTML = "TextBalk geupdate!"; 
}
```

**Edit**
I found the solution, the problem was that I called an 'onkeypress' event, which can fire before the key is released, meaning the input is cleared, and after that, an enter is placed. I fixed it by using the onkeyup event, and canceling this event when the pressed key was the enter key.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: If your inputs are inside a `<form>` then you can use the `<input type="reset">` to reset all the values inside the form. This means if the original input looks like this `<input type="text" value="test"/>` then the reset input will return the value back to `test` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/reset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the timing in the events.

I called an 'onkeypress' event, which fires before the key is released, meaning the input is cleared, and after that, an enter is placed. I fixed it by using the onkeyup event, and canceling this event when the pressed key was the enter key.